# DataGrid dynamic columns in grid from complex nested object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am writing a WPF application using MVVM, I am trying to bind a nested complex object to a datagrid. I basically need to create the datagrid dynamically and I only know at run time how many columns it will have also the columns need to be generated from the rows...

The MetaDataDO class,

```
public class MetaDataDO
{
    public int MetaItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
    public IList<ItemDO> Volumes { get; set; }
}
```

The ItemDO class,

```
public class ItemDO
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public int Period { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

In my view model I have a property ObservableCollection MetaDataCollection that can have N number of MetaDataDO, each MetaDataDO will have 4 Prices in it. Example data below...

```
MetaDataCollection
1, UK, 10, 
           Volumes
                  1, 24/01/2014 00:00, 24/01/2014 06:00, 1, 100
                  2, 24/01/2014 06:00, 24/01/2014 12:00, 2, 120  
                  3, 24/01/2014 12:00, 24/01/2014 18:00, 3, 110
                  4, 24/01/2014 18:00, 24/01/2014 24:00, 4, 150

2, UAE, 20, 
           Volumes
                  1, 24/01/2014 00:00, 24/01/2014 06:00, 1, 500
                  2, 24/01/2014 06:00, 24/01/2014 12:00, 2, 140  
                  3, 24/01/2014 12:00, 24/01/2014 18:00, 3, 510
                  4, 24/01/2014 18:00, 24/01/2014 24:00, 4, 550
....
```

I have no control over how these existing objects are defined, these are being returned by an external system. Once I receive the data in my viewmodel,

I want to display the results on the UI in a datagrid in the following format,

```
  Start          |        End       |  UK | USA
-----------------------------------------------
24/01/2014 00:00 | 24/01/2014 06:00 | 100 | 500 
24/01/2014 06:00 | 24/01/2014 12:00 | 120 | 140 
24/01/2014 12:00 | 24/01/2014 18:00 | 110 | 510 
24/01/2014 18:00 | 24/01/2014 24:00 | 150 | 550
```

so in simple terms, i am trying to bind the property to the radGridView in the following way...

```
            Start            |             End                  |                                           UK                                                                                            |                       USA
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MetaDataCollection[0].Volumes[0].Start | MetaDataCollection[0].Volumes[0].End | MetaDataCollection[0].Volumes[0].Price | MetaDataCollection[1].Volumes[0].Price 

    MetaDataCollection[0].Volumes[1].Start | MetaDataCollection[0].Volumes[1].End | MetaDataCollection[0].Volumes[1].Price | MetaDataCollection[1].Volumes[1].Price 

    MetaDataCollection[0].Volumes[2].Start | MetaDataCollection[0].Volumes[2].End | MetaDataCollection[0].Volumes[2].Price | MetaDataCollection[1].Volumes[2].Price 

    MetaDataCollection[0].Volumes[3].Start | MetaDataCollection[0].Volumes[3].End | MetaDataCollection[0].Volumes[3].Price | MetaDataCollection[1].Volumes[3].Price
```

How do I bind the property which is really a complex nested object to the datagrid to achieve this output format?

Comment: Check [`this`](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/676530/How-to-Add-Columns-to-a-DataGrid-through-Binding-a) article, there are added dynamically columns through *attached* dependency property.

Comment: Sorry doesn't help. I have added more description to my question. I am trying to bind a collection of collection where columns are picked from collection and value from collection of collection.

Comment: I have got it to work, but i must say the technique i am using is not elegant. So i am keeping the question open. The technique i have used is to create a datatable and bind the datagrid to the datatable. But it's very non MVVM friendly in nature.